# 2 boys and 4 girls stand in a circle.

Tags: combinatorics

Count the ways in which 2 boys and 4 girls can stand in a circle. (rotations of the same pattern are identical).

I am manually counting 3 patterns for this. I do not know if there is a general formula that we can come up with.

$\textbf{[Harder]}$ Count the ways in which 10 different boys can stand in a circle. (rotations of the same pattern are identical).

Comment: If we were considering each persons individual name, then the problem would be completely different. We wouldn't need to consider the boys name and the girls name.

Comment: That's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial solution, but too long for a comment.  Suppose there are $b>1$ boys and $g>1$ girls.  Fix some position that will have a boy in it.  The remaining children can be arranged in the circle, counterclockwise from the starting boy, in $$\frac{(g+b-1)!}{(b-1)!g!}$$ ways.  However, we can rotate any of the boys to the staring position, and have the same cyclic arrangement, so each pattern has been counted $b$ times.  This gives $$\frac{(g+b-1)!}{b!g!}$$ patterns.

The problem with this is that some rotation may leave the arrangement fixed, so that there is no double counting.  If we try the above formula with $g=4, b=2$ we get $$\frac{5!}{2!4!}=\frac52.$$  The problem is the the arrangement BGGBGG, when rotated gives exactly the same arrangement.  The correct answer is given by $$\frac12\left(\frac{5!}{1!4!}-1\right)+1=3$$

To solve the problem in general, we have to work out how many rotations there are that leave the arrangement fixed.  In general, it may be that some of the rotations leave the pattern fixed, and some don't.  In the pattern,

BGBGGGBGBGGG

rotating by $5$ leaves the pattern fixed, but rotating by $2$ does not.

I doubt there's a general formula.  you probably have to investigate each case separately.  I imagine that [Polya's theory of counting](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Polya.pdf) comes into it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for the first question the boys are indistinguishable, and same for the girls, then yes, there are $3$ patterns: there can be $0$, $1$, or $2$ girls between the two boys.

You may want to ask your instructor though if indeed the boys are all regarded as the same, and same for the girls ...

For the second question: Here are two ways to think about that one:

First: What are the possible number of line-ups of $10$ different boys?  So when you make the line into a circle, and get rotational symmetry, then how many line-ups would end up becoming the same circle?  Divide the number of lines-ups by that number and you have the number of different circles.

A second method is this: take one of the $10$ boys, and place this boy anywhere at the table. By rotational symmetry, it does not matter where this first boy ends up.  However, once this first boy is seated, it kind of 'anchors' the table. That is, depending on who gets seated to the right of the first boy, you get a different arrangement. In fact, there are $9$ boys left who can be seated to the right of the first boy.  And now there are $8$ left who can be seats to the right of the second boy, etc. So from this you can get the right formula as well.

Comment: If every individual was distinguishable then there would be no need to consider that there are 2 boys or 4 girls. Nothing comes to mind for the 2nd question.

Comment: @mk3009hppw Yes, makes sense: so why not ask the question with $6$ boys, right?  Still, you never know ... I would confirm with your instructor that that is what is meant.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the solution might involve choosing a pair from the circle and then counting how many people can be between that pair, and then multiplying that by the possible arrangements of those people in between.

Comment: @mk3009hppw Yikes, that sounds far too difficult .. I just gave a hint in my Answer

Comment: so are you getting $5 * 8!$? if you pick a pair then they can have 0 to 4 people in between them and then 8! ways for each of those to be arranged.

Comment: @mk3009hppw No, don't think about this in terms of pairs at all.  I just added another way to think about this ...

Comment: If you have a 10 length line then you can shift it 1 to the right and restore the excess to the beginning a total of 9 times to get 9 additional strings, so 10!/10 = $9!$.

Comment: @mk3009hppw That's exactly it!  Yes, you just had to think in basic permutations. So: $10!$ possible line-ups, but $10$ different line-ups lead to the same circle, so divide by $10$. Or, following the second hint:  the first boy can go anywhere, but now the locations are fixed, and so you're left with $9$ possible ways to seat the remaining $9$ boys.

Comment: Oh I understand Why I thought this method was wrong initially. Suppose you have 10101, If you rotate it twice you still have 10101, but you are dividing that string 5 times. But that only applies for if you have repetitions like Boy Girl Boy Girl Boy. If everyone is unique then you don't have that problem.